# Thought process

Tags: electrons, electric-current, charge, conventions

Voltage = Energy/ Charge

If voltage comes out of the negative terminal through a wire to do the powering and then end up at the positive terminal, then what is it that comes out the positive terminal.

current.

all right so whats current.

current is coulombs.

then whats coulombs.

coulombs are electrons with charge.

**Question:** How could coulombs of electrons with charge come out of the
positive terminal as electric current if they are suppose to come out of the negative terminal?

> If anyone could help with this by shedding some insight or answering
>   the last sentence above instead of just DOWNVOTING, you might
>   be at risk of being the better person. Instead of acting like some
>   stuck up brainiack snob.

Comment: Nothing comes out: electrons go into it.

Comment: @tfb that was helpful.

Comment: as far as your last sentence, note that I=dQ/dt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current#Metals ) . It is convention. If a direction is given to I, the positive charge  moves in the direction of   I the negative against it.

Comment: I just want to thank all those here who gave their time and sincere effort to trying to answer or help this poor question. To all those who just bitterly down voted and put my question on hold, you know who you are, your not worth writing about any longer. @Qmechanic I appreciate your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If voltage comes out of the negative terminal

Voltage is an across variable, not a flow variable; voltage does not 'come out' of a terminal.

> then what is it that comes out the positive terminal.
>
> current.

If power is delivered to the circuit element, the *electric* (not *electron*) current is *in* to the more positive terminal.  If power is supplied by the circuit element, the current is *out* of the more positive terminal.

> all right so whats current.

(Electric) current is a flow of electric charge.

> current is coulombs.

(Electric) current is a flow of electric charge.

> then whats coulombs.

The Coulomb is the unit for the *amount* of electric charge.

> coulombs are electrons with charge.

The Coulomb is the unit for the *amount* of electric charge.  There are no electrons without charge.

> How could coulombs of electrons with charge come out of the positive
>   terminal as electric current if they are suppose to come out of the
>   negative terminal.

Electrons have *negative* electric charge and thus flow in the direction *opposite* to the direction of electric current (*electron* current direction is opposite to *electric* current direction).

If electrons *exit* the more positive terminal, the electric current *enters* the more positive terminal and, thus, the circuit element is being *supplied* power, e.g., a resistor.

However, for a battery supplying power to a load, the electrons exit the more negative terminal of the battery.

Comment: @ Alfred." (electron current direction is opposite to electric current direction)." what! how could that be if the electron current is the one taking charge through the wire to the element making it WORK . "

Comment: @MacR.  see the answer here https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-direction-of-flow-of-electrons-opposite-to-the-direction-of-flow-of-electric-current

Comment: @MacR. electron current is the flow of electrons, a flow of objects which have the *property* of being electrically charged.   Electric current, in contrast, is the flow of electric charge without regard to the entities that 'carry' it.  While it is true that electrons are the mobile charge carriers in metal, consider the charge carriers in, for example, an electrolyte within a battery.   In that case, you might find that both positively and negatively charged ions flow (in opposite directions) and yet, there is just *one* electric current and it is in the direction of  positive charge flow.

Comment: @ Alfred   "  Electric current, in contrast, is the flow of electric charge without regard to the entities that 'carry' it. "   I feel that is like saying a car driving on the freeway empty and with no driver.   "  there is just one electric current and it is in the direction of positive charge flow.  "   would that positive charge flow happen to be on the electrons or protons.

Comment: @MacR., (1) your question makes no sense to me and (2) I'm not interested in working this out with you in this comment section.

Comment: @Alfred Fine. once again, appreciate your efforts and time.

Comment: no use, I give up.

Comment: @MacR., [here's a related answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/39852/10475)  I posted on the Electrical Engineering site; perhaps it will help.

Comment: @Alfred, I appreciate you getting back to me about this.Your answer was the best answer I've gotten so far from people here. +1. And as appreciative as I am for it, it did raise 2 other questions if you decide they are valid enough and you want to answer. 1) does everything you said there apply to a metal wire (cable). 2) through a metal wire, does anyone know which one kicks-off first, to which side does the first domino fall to, (to the - or +).

Answer (score 3):

Before I answer your question, let's start with correcting your first statements. First of all: voltage does not "come out of" the battery. The voltage is a scalar field which represents the electrical potential energy per unit charge. It has a certain value at every point in space. It is not a physical thing that is moving out of the battery.

Next, current is not measured in Coulombs, it is measured in Amperes: a current of 1 Ampere means 1 Coulomb of charge is passing by in 1 second.

As for your question, I believe what you're confused by is the difference between the direction of the electric current, and the direction of movement of the electrons. In your battery example, what is actually flowing is the *electrons*. However, the convention is that we assign to electrons a *negative* charge. Because the electric current is defined as the direction of flow of *positive* charge, the direction of the electric current opposes that of the actual electron flow.

This sometimes confusing convention seems to originate from Benjamin Franklin, see for example: http://www-spof.gsfc.nasa.gov/Education/woppos.html

Comment: appreciate your answer. but " Because the electric current is defined as the direction of flow of positive charge, " how could that be if the NEGATIVE electrons "shooting/bumping" out of  the negative terminal through the wire is the one with CHARGE.

Comment: @MacR. Again, it is just a matter of convention. Benjamin Franklin did not know about the existence of electrons. He found that when you rub certain materials together, each of them becomes charged (now known as the [tribo-electric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect)) . He then (pretty much arbitrarily) called one of them positively charged and the other negatively charged, and postulated that the current runs form + to -. Over a century later, electrons were discovered. These were found to be responsible for the electric current, and they run from (Franklin's) - to +.

Comment: "  Over a century later, ELECTRONS were discovered. THESE were found to be responsible for the ELECTRIC CURRENT, and they run from (Franklin's) - to +.  " exactly! Try reading Alfred's last comments and let me know if they match yours.